# How can I fill a probably infinite amount of dropdowns iterating through objects from a JSON file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

So, I'm trying to fill three separate dropdown menus (could end up being more) with objects pulled from different JSON files depending on the selection from each dropdown. So first selection fills the second one, and so on.

These are the dropdown menus:

```
<form>
    <div>
        <select id="level1">
            <option selected value="base">Please select one</option>
            <option value="first-option">First one</option>
            <option value="second-option">Second one</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div>
        <select id="level2" class="form-control">
            <option selected value="base">Please select one</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div>
        <select id="level3" class="form-control">
            <option selected value="base">Please select one</option>
        </select>
    </div>

    <div id="submit">
        <button type="submit">Go</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

This is a sample JSON file:

```
{
  "first_option": {
    "me": "first_option",
    "COD_REF": "MX09017CL01AP",
    "TITLE": "First Option",
    "children": {
      "child01": {
        "me": "child01",
        "COD_REF": "001",
        "TITLE": "Child 1",
        "children": {
          "grandchild01": {
            "me": "grandchild01",
            "TITLE": "Grandchild 1"
          },
          "grandchild02": {
            "me": "grandchild01",
            "TITLE": "Grandchild 1"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "child02": {
      "me": "child02",
      "COD_REF": "002",
      "TITLE": "Child 2",
      "children": {
        "grandchild01": {
          "me": "grandchild01",
          "TITLE": "Grandchild 1"
        },
        "grandchild02": {
          "me": "grandchild01",
          "TITLE": "Grandchild 1"
        }
      }
    },
  }
}
```

The solution I came up with works just fine. The thing is I could probably do with some iteration, I just don't know how to do it. Here's an abridged version of what I have:

```
var vals = [];
var $level1 = $("#level1");
var $level2 = $("#level2");
var $level3 = $("#level3");

function generateTable(info) {
  $(".COD_REF").innerHTML(info.COD_REF);
  $(".TITLE").innerHTML(info.TITLE);
};

function generateTable2(info) {
  $(".COD_REF").innerHTML(info.COD_REF);
  $(".TITLE").innerHTML(info.TITLE);
}

function generateTable3(info) {
  $(".COD_REF").innerHTML(info.COD_REF);
  $(".TITLE").innerHTML(info.TITLE);
}

//first dropdown
$("#level1").change(function () {
  var $dropdown = $(this);
  var key = $dropdown.val();

  function generateDropdown(vals) {
    $level2.append("<option selected value=\"base\">Please select one</option>");
    $.each(vals, function (index, value) {
      $level2.append("<option value=\"" + value.me + "\">" + value.TITLE + "</option>");
    });
  };

  switch (key) {
    case 'first_option':
    $.getJSON("recursos/json/ajsonfile.json", function (data) {
      $level2.empty();

      vals = data.first_option.children;
      generateDropdown(vals)

      $("#first-table").removeClass("d-none");
      $("#first-table").addClass("d-block");

      info = data.first_option;
      $(".first-title").innerHTML(info.TITLE);
      generateTable(info);
    });
    break
    case 'second_option':
    $.getJSON("recursos/json/anotherjsonfile.json", function (data) {
      $level2.empty();

      vals = data.second_option.children;
      generateDropdown(vals)

      $("#first-table").removeClass("d-none");
      $("#first-table").addClass("d-block");

      info = data.second_option;
      $(".first-title").innerHTML(info.TITLE);
      generateTable(info);
    });
    break
    case 'base':
    $level2.empty();
    vals = ['Please select one'];
    $level2.append("<option>" + vals + "</option>");
    $("#first-table").removeClass("d-block");
    $("#first-table").addClass("d-none");
    console.log(vals);
    break
  }
});

//second dropdown
$("#level2").change(function () {
  var $dropdown = $(this);
  var key = $dropdown.val();

  function generateDropdown(vals) {
    $level3.append("<option selected value=\"base\">Please select one</option>");
    $.each(vals, function (index, value) {
      $level3.append("<option value=\"" + value.yo + "\">" + value.TITLE + "</option>");
    });
  };

  switch (key) {
    case 'first-child':
    $.getJSON("recursos/json/ajsonfile.json", function (data) {
      $level3.empty();

      vals = data.first_option.children.child01.children;
      generateDropdown(vals)

      $("#second-table").removeClass("d-none");
      $("#second-table").addClass("d-block");

      info = data.first_option.children.child01;
      $(".second-title").innerHTML(info.TITLE);
      generateTable2(info);
    });
    break

    //second, third, fourth child options etc.

    case 'base':
    $level3.empty();
    vals = ['Please select one'];
    $level3.append("<option>" + vals + "</option>");
    $("#cedula2").removeClass("d-block");
    $("#cedula2").addClass("d-none");
    console.log(vals);
    break
  }
});

//third dropdown
$("#level3").change(function () {
  // I think you get the gist
});
```

Is it possible to do some iteration so I can fill all the dropdowns in just one loop?